# Ambiguous meaning of "turn your back on"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I read a sentence that goes "Don't turn your back on racism" from the statement of a large US company.

As a non-native-English-speaker, I always thought "turn your back on" meant "reject". But then this sentence clearly doesn't mean "Don't reject racism". So I googled and it could also mean "ignore". OK now "Don't ignore racism" makes sense.

But does this phrase really have these two completely opposing meanings?

Comment: You think 'reject' and 'ignore' have opposing meanings?

Comment: Depending on the sentence, yes. "Don't reject racism" and "Don't ignore racism" are very different.

Comment: Yes. "Don't turn your back on racism" means "Don't turn a blind eye to racism", "Don't fail to _**oppose**_ racism". But "Don't turn your back on the old ways" means "Continue to _**embrace**_ them". Keep both your enemies (racism) and your friends (cherished customs) close.

Comment: I see "Don't turn your back on racism" as meaning "Don't ignore racism or pretend that does not exist". No sane officials of a 'large US company' are going to urge their staff, or anyone else, 'not to reject' racism.

Comment: The context makes the meaning abundantly clear: "Don't pretend there's not a problem in America.  Don't turn your back on racism.  Don't accept innocent lives being taken from us.  Don't make any more excuses.  Don't think this doesn't affect you.  Don't sit back and be silent.  Don't think you can't be part of the change.  Let's all be part of the change."

Comment: If you "turn your back" on a financial transaction you reject it.  If you "turn your back" on an act of violence you ignore it.  The meaning is clear if you consider the physical movement (turning so that your back faces the activity) in those situations.